# How to add same data in two schemas by same route in node js?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

The route is `/upload` and schemas are

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    others : {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
});
```

and other one is

```
var HomeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    others : {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with using an identifier within the JSON?  Something like `type: "Home"` and `type: "User"`.  I usually work with MongoClient and not an ORM but as I understand it you are declaring two different collections in this case.  So even though the data is the same, they are seen as two different Schemas because you declared them as such.

Comment: What do you want to 'add' to your documents ? from where are your getting your `data` ?

Comment: This is schema of form and user will enter his data.